# Importing Bulk Images into SQL Server using Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, t-sql, fetch

I am trying to draft a SQL script that will loop to insert image files into a SQL Server table matching based on ID. I have named the image files based on the customerID I have in my database. I want to figure out a way to loop through the member ID's and insert the images into my table. Below is my current code.

```
Declare @CUSTCD int, @EVENTCD nvarchar(50), @SIGNATURES varbinary(max)

SET @SIGNATURES = Select BulkColumn from Openrowset (Bulk 'C:\sigs\'+ @CUSTCD int+ '.png', Single_Blob) as Image

-- declare a cursor DECLARE insert_cursor CURSOR FOR select @CUSTCD,'75thCelebration', BulkColumn from Openrowset (Bulk 'C:\sigs\'+(Select @CUSTCD from CUS)+'119.png', Single_Blob) as Image --SELECT CUSTCD , EVENTCD, SIGNATURES from CUS_SIGS2 --WHERE CUSTCD = 78

-- open cursor and fetch first row into variables OPEN insert_cursor FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor into @CUSTCD, @EVENTCD, @SIGNATURES

-- check for a new row WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 BEGIN -- do complex operation here Insert into CUS_SIGS2
SELECT @CUSTCD, @EVENTCD, @SIGNATURES -- get next available row into variables FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor into @CUSTCD, @EVENTCD, @SIGNATURES END close insert_cursor Deallocate insert_cursor GO
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to know how I can do a bulk import of 200 image files into a SQL Server Database Table

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your code is a complete mess. I think this is roughly what you are trying to do:

```
declare @CUSTCD int, @EVENTCD nvarchar(50), @SIGNATURES varbinary(max)

declare insert_cursor cursor for select CUSTCD from CUS

open insert_cursor  
fetch next from insert_cursor into @CUSTCD 

while @@fetch_status = 0  
begin  

    set @SIGNATURES = Select BulkColumn from Openrowset (Bulk 'C:\sigs\'+ @CUSTCD int+ '.png', Single_Blob) as Image

    -- "do complex operation here Insert into CUS_SIGS2"

    fetch next from insert_cursor into @CUSTCD 
end 

close insert_cursor  
deallocate insert_cursor
```

Although I don't know where `@EVENTCD` is supposed to come from.